# Python - Multiprocessing with multiple for-loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I know there are other questions asked concerning this topic so I'm sorry I have to ask it again, but I cannot get it to work since I'm quite new to this topic.

I have four for-loop (nested) in which certain algbraic calculations are done (matrix operations for example). These calculations take too much time to complete, so I was hoping I could speed this up with Multiprocessing.

The code is given below. I simulated the ranges and matrix sizes here, but in my code these ranges are really used (so it's not strange that it takes so long). You should be able to run it directly when copy-paste the code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import fractional_matrix_power
import math

#Lists for the loop (and one value)
x_list = np.arange(0, 32, 1)
y_list = np.arange(0, 32, 1)
a_list = np.arange(0, 501, 1)
b_list = np.arange(0, 501, 1)
c_list = np.arange(0, 64, 1)
d_number = 32

#Matrices
Y = np.arange(2048).reshape(32, 64)
g = np.asmatrix(np.empty([d_number, 1], dtype=np.complex_))
A = np.empty([len(a_list), len(b_list), len(c_list)], dtype=np.complex_)
A_in = np.empty([len(a_list), len(b_list)], dtype=np.complex_)


for ai in range(len(a_list)):
    
    for bi in range(len(b_list)):
        
        for ci in range(len(c_list)):
            
            f_k_i = c_list[ci]
            X_i = np.asmatrix([Y[:, ci]]).T
            
            for di in range(d_number):
                
                r = math.sqrt((x_list[di] - a_list[ai])**2 + (y_list[di] - b_list[bi])**2 + 63**2)
                g[di, 0] = np.exp(-2 * np.pi * 1j * f_k_i * (r / 8)) / r #g is a vector
            
            A[-bi, -ai, ci] = ((1 / np.linalg.norm(g)**2) * (((g.conj().T * fractional_matrix_power((X_i * X_i.conj().T), (1/5)) * g) / np.linalg.norm(g)**2)**2)).item(0)
         
        A_in[-bi, -ai] = (1 / len(c_list)) * sum(A[-bi, -ai, :])
```

What is the best way to approach this? If multiprocessing is the solution, how to implement this for my case (since I couldn't figure that out).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `multiprocessing` is good when you can split calculate on smaller elements which can run  separatelly but in your code one `for`-loop depends on other `for`-loop so I don't see how to run it in `multiprocessing`, `threading` or any other module.

Comment: you may try to split array/list `c_list` to smaller arrays/lists and for every array/list run separated thread or process.

Comment: And when I have split the c_list, how can I run every section on a seperate thread?

Comment: you would have to get code from loop `for ci in` and put in function - ie. `calculate(part_of_ci_list)`  - and then for every part of list ci run `Thread(target=calculate, args=(part_of_ci_list,))`. But it need also method to get all results from thread, and get them in correct order - and this is why sometimes using threads or processes makes only more problems.

Comment: Okay so speeding this thing up will cause only more problems probably, there must be a way right?

Comment: I tried to run it with `ThreadPool` but after short time it gives me `SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)` which means problem with memory (probably it tries to access memory which doesn't belong to thread) and probably it would need some method to block other threads when one thread write data to shared variable - and make problem and it can slow down threads.

Comment: What is the "output" of the nested loops? `g`, `A`, and `A_in` get calculated are they all used later?

Comment: @RootTwo Only A_in is used later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach it would be to move the two inside loops into a function taking `ai` and `bi` as parameters and returning the indexes and the result. Then use `multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered()` to run the function on `ai`, `bi` pairs. Something like this (untested):

```
def partial_calc(index):
    """
    This function replaces the inner two loops to calculate the value of
    A_in[-bi, -ai]. index is a tuple (ai, bi).
    """

    ai, bi = index

    for ci in range(len(c_list)):
        
        f_k_i = c_list[ci]
        X_i = np.asmatrix([Y[:, ci]]).T
        
        for di in range(d_number):
            
            r = math.sqrt((x_list[di] - a_list[ai])**2 + (y_list[di] - b_list[bi])**2 + 63**2)
            g[di, 0] = np.exp(-2 * np.pi * 1j * f_k_i * (r / 8)) / r #g is a vector
        
        A[-bi, -ai, ci] = ((1 / np.linalg.norm(g)**2) * (((g.conj().T * fractional_matrix_power((X_i * X_i.conj().T), (1/5)) * g) / np.linalg.norm(g)**2)**2)).item(0)
        
    return ai, bi, (1 / len(c_list)) * sum(A[-bi, -ai, :])
    

def main():

    with multiprocessing.Pool(None) as p:
        # this replaces the outer two loops
        indices = itertools.product(range(len(a_list)), range(len(b_list)))

        partial_results = p.imap_unordered(partial_calc, indices)        
         
        for ai, bi, value in partial_results:
            A_in[-bi, -ai] = value

    #... do something with A_in ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Or put the inner three loops into the function and generate one "row" for `A_in` at a time.  Profile it both ways and see which is faster.

The trick will be setting up the lists (a_list, b_list, etc) and the Y matrix.  And that depends on their characteristics (constant, quickly/slowly calculated, large/small, etc).

Comment: Thanks! So I tried this but I get the error: TypeError: partial_calc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bi'. I understand the error, but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I did set the Indices to the following: indices = list(itertools.product(range(len(a_list)), range(len(b_list))))

Comment: The error is because `itertools.product` yields single values: (ai, bi) tuples.  So, `partial_calc` should take one argument that gets unpacked in the function.  Fixed.  Note, the code isn't complete, e.g.,  the lists and matrix needs to be set up.

Comment: That's it! I changed the code a bit because of the tuples and it works like a charm, thanks a lot!